# Angular Bootstrap 4 collapse opening/closing all items

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

I am trying to only have 1 item in my ngFor expand/close using the boostrap 4 collapse component.

This is my code

```
<div class="card-footer account clickthrough" *ngFor="let attachment of item.attachments; let j=index" (click)="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed" [attr.aria-expanded]="!isCollapsed"
        aria-controls="collapseExample">
        Attachment {{j+1}}
    <div id="collapseExample" [ngbCollapse]="isCollapsed">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <p>Attachment ID: {{attachment.id}}</p>
          <p>Attachment Delivery Message: {{attachment.attachToDeliveryMessage}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is a screenshot of my UI
[image]

So currently if I click on an attachment item all of the attachment items will expand/close all at the same time. I just need the clicked on attachment item to expand/close

Comment: You have one single `isCollapsed` variable for all the divs... you should have it against each `item.attachments`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is you are relying on a single variable and trying to toggle on all click, so you must need individual variables to bind. Either way is to create sperate variables for each item which is not recommended in such cases so you can try this -

```
<div *ngFor="let attachment of item.attachments; let j = index" (click)="attachment.isCollapsed = !attachment.isCollapsed" [attr.aria-expanded]="!isCollapsed" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Attachment {{j+1}}
    <div id="collapseExample" [ngbCollapse]="attachment.isCollapsed">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>Attachment ID: {{attachment.id}}</p>
                <p>Attachment Delivery Message: {{attachment.attachToDeliveryMessage}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```